# Listing different images along with text in android?

Tags: android

..i want to list different images..so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont fully understand your exact requirement. Anyways, you can use ListViews to make a list of images and textviews.

Assuming you want to have a ListView in which each row must contain an image and a text, you must define an xml inside /layout/ folder. Here is an example custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```